# Clip-path doesn't work corectly on web browswers (Mozilla, Edge, Chrome) but works perfectly on preview Visual Code Studio HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, clip-path, mousehover

I want to create a fancy hero section for my company. I'm using clip-path and some JS to achieve a paint spray effect on mouse move, and it works perfectly in the VCS preview. However, when I try it in web browsers like Chrome, Mozilla, or Edge, it doesn't work. It seems like the cursor's position can't be found properly. The clip-path shows in random places and for a few seconds or doesn't show at all.
What's more? if its i left corner without margin: auto; it's work great but it had to be center.

Page where i want to use it: https://hoffmannteile.de/
Here's the code I'm using (it has to be in one file because it's a closed CMS):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const cars = document.querySelectorAll('.car');
    cars.forEach(car => {
        car.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            const x = e.pageX - car.offsetLeft;
            const y = e.pageY - car.offsetTop;

            car.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
            car.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.paint {
  max-height: 338px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.malowanie {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cont .car {
  position: relative;
  height: 338px;
  width: 600px;
  background-image: url('https://composer.idosell.com/gfx/30226/SprinterWhite.png');
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cont .car::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cont .car::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: var(--img);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: circle(0px at 0 0);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: clip-path 0.15s;
}

.cont .car:hover::after {
  clip-path: circle(100px at var(--x) var(--y));
  cursor: url('https://composer.idosell.com/gfx/30226/paint-spray-icon.svg'), auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="paint">
    <div class="malowanie">
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="car" style="--img: url('https://composer.idosell.com/gfx/30226/SprinterRedHof.png')"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: To compute your x and y, instead of using the potentially confusing `offset` values (which only define the offset between the element and its first parent), try using `element.getBoundingClientRect().x` and `.y` and see if that makes it more consistent. Please also add your below "answer" to your post and remove the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mouse coordinate relative to the `clientX/Y` and use [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) `left` and `top` values

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const cars = document.querySelectorAll('.car');
  cars.forEach(car => {
    car.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      const bcr = car.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = e.clientX - bcr.left;
      const y = e.clientY - bcr.top;
      car.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
      car.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 300px; /* just to test scroll */
}

.paint {
  max-height: 338px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.malowanie {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cont .car {
  position: relative;
  height: 338px;
  width: 600px;
  background-image: url('https://composer.idosell.com/gfx/30226/SprinterWhite.png');
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cont .car::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cont .car::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: var(--img);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: circle(0px at 0 0);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: clip-path 0.15s;
}

.cont .car:hover::after {
  clip-path: circle(100px at var(--x) var(--y));
  cursor: url('https://composer.idosell.com/gfx/30226/paint-spray-icon.svg'), auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some title to test offset</h1>
<section class="paint">
  <div class="malowanie">
    <div class="cont">
      <div class="car" style="--img: url('https://composer.idosell.com/gfx/30226/SprinterRedHof.png')"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```